# Relative date range in reports filter

Tags: date, criteria-filter

I am trying to generate a report for my end user based on date range.
I used the filter in reports

e.g. 
Issused date greater or equal 01/01/2016 (start date)
AND
Issused date less or equal 31/12/2016 (end date --> always 1 year from start date)

Is it possible to set some formula in the filter rules such that my user only need to enter the whatever start date & Salesforce will automatically compute 1 year from start date

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No. Salesforce does support date literals, such as "THIS YEAR", "LAST YEAR", or even "NEXT 6 MONTHS", but you can't create a date "formula" in that sense.